# different ways of adding node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

This simple code (adding element to linked list and printing it) works fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct node{
    int item;
    struct node* next;
};

void print_node (struct node* n){
    while (n!= NULL){
        printf("%d ", (*n).item);
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void append_node(struct node *list, struct node *n){

    while(list->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;

    list->next = n;

}

int main(){
    struct node n1, n2;
    n1.item = 1;
    n1.next = NULL;

    n2.item = 2;
    n2.next = NULL;

    print_node(&n1);
    print_node(&n2);

    append_node(&n1,&n2);

    print_node(&n1);

    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If instead I define the append_node as following

```
void append_node(struct node *list, struct node n){

    while(list->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;

    list->next = &n;

}
```

and call it accordingly in the main (i.e., `append_node(&n1, n2)` ) I get a segmentation fault when running the program. And I don't understand why :)

Comment: `struct node n` is local variable. Invalid in the scope of the outside of the function.

Comment: At least half the LL questions asked in this tag have the same 'local var' issue:(

Comment: Ops, sorry, probably I did not search for the right keywords...
BTW, it's mainly java's fault. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `append_node(struct node *list, struct node n)`, the argument `n` is copied on the function context.

When the function is leave, the context is freed, and the copy `n` of your data is lost.

You could use your function `append_node(struct node *list, struct node n)` if you make a copy of `n` (using `malloc`) before putting it in linked list.

*EDIT*

This may help you: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: the content of n inside the function is erased from memory even though it has been linked to list?

Comment: Yes: in your linked list, you just put the address of `n`, which is local to the function. You may run add some `printf("address of n is %p\n", &n);` to visualise that. In that case you may notice that addresses generated by malloc and stack addresses are different.

Comment: All the function variables(arguments) are stored on stack and when function returns all its variables get destroyed(inaccessible, may contain some other data).

Comment: OK, then (just for the sake of understanding), I want to modify the function print_node so that it does not receive a pointer.
I managed in writing it like this (it works):

void print_node (struct node n){
 while (1){
  printf("%d ", n.item);
  if (n.next == NULL)
   break;
  n = *(n.next);
 }
 printf("\n");
}

How could I write in the while something like n!=NULL, when n is not a pointer, in order to not do the break inside the loop?

Comment: @Peter: You can do so if you want. Just make sure to assign the `next` node pointers in a local `struct node* n` and using appropriate `printf` for it.